# Do Bluray releases contain more scenes than their DVD counterparts?

Tags: anime-production

Most of the time I opt for the DVD Release because I can back it up easier (don't have a Bluray driver and unsure if my current programs work with Bluray) however in some cases I do get the Bluray release, this normally happens because it either comes with something extra (Blood C came with a calendar) or are limited editions (like most of the NISA ones, Puella Magi Madoka Magica)

In some of my NISA Limited Edition Anime and Puella Magi Madoka Magica Limited Edition they come with both the DVD and Bluray Release, when testing out my Bluray Player to make sure it could play US Bluray (because I had brought it for Fate/Zero) all I noticed was that the animation was much more smoother. (increase in)

Because I have a large backlog of anime I still haven't watched when I finish a series I move onto the next or I don't remember enough of the beginning of the series to notice any changes (in some cases even re-watching the DVDs have new scenes, in Madoka Magica I don't remember seeing a scene where Sayaka hold out her soul gem with a red background behind her in my first view of the series, second view was on TV)

So I am wondering, between a Bluray Release of an anime and it's DVD counterpart, does a bluray have more scenes in it or is it just the quality difference?

Comment: I find no difference in the description of [Guilty Crown DVD Vol 1](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3-1%E3%80%90%E5%AE%8C%E5%85%A8%E7%94%9F%E7%94%A3%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E7%89%88%E3%80%91-DVD-%E6%A2%B6-%E8%A3%95%E8%B2%B4/dp/B005WO7XZE/) and [Guilty Crown BD Vol 1](http://www.amazon.co.jp/ギルティクラウン-1【完全生産限定版】-Blu-ray-梶-裕貴/dp/B005WO7WE6/) (both limited version) - it probably means the content of the disc and the extras are the same. This is the only one that I checked, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no, much like any other blue-ray content (e.g., movies).

When releasing the blue-ray version, the publishers will always want as many people as possible to buy it. To do it (especially if the Blue-ray release follows a TV release and a DVD release which means a lot of potential customers have already bought something), they need to somehow raise your interest to the blue ray. Since a Blue-ray disc provides much more space than, say, a DVD disk, that gives them a chance to interest you:

- Higher quality video
- Higher quality audio (e.g. lossless audio formats)
- More audio tracks (original audio, dubbed audio, maybe an audio commentary from the authors, etc. etc.)
- Additional bonus content (interviews, films about "how this was made", soundtrack, and so on)
- Bonus scenes/director's cut.
- Other merchandise (posters/books/artbooks/anything-else-you-can-imagine-just-pay-for-it).

For example, [here](http://www.mania.com/aodvb/showthread.php?t=109275) is the Fate/Zero Blue-ray box, which costs a hell lot, and includes, among other stuff,

> - Extras: New bonus animation (written by Kinoko Nasu), Trailers, TV Spots, Textless Opening and Ending
> - Episodes: Episodes 1-13 with unaired new footage

However, I wouldn't say that "most of", or at least "a lot of" Blue-ray releases contain bonus scenes, but unfortunately I can't prove myself with any facts, because apparently there's no such statistics in the Internet.

Comment: Its Blu-Ray, not Blue-Ray.